# Display text when input tag checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I am trying to display a text when the user selects the `input` tag,

For example, I have the following code:

```
<tr>
    <td class="align">
        Yes <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Once the user clicks on the check box, the following text will appear:

> "If you have selected yes,....."

And **I am not sure** if JavaScript would be the best path to do this.

**But**, If it is, would it be something like:

```
<script>
    $(function(){ 
         if(input was checked)//not sure what would go here, new to Javascript
             display results//not sure either, new to Javascript
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you search anything as you are new in this ? Any references you found ?

Answer (score 2):

If you can put the text after, you can do it in CSS.

```html
Yes<br />
<input type="checkbox" />
<span class="message">You have said Yes</span>
```

```css
.message {
   display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .message {
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#checkbox").click(function() {
 $("#clickedYes").toggle($(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

```css
#clickedYes {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Yes <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<span id="clickedYes">If you have selected yes....</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, To get the checkbox  value, do something like this

`$("input[type='checkbox']").val();`

or you can get with class/id by

`$('.chekboxClass').val();`
`$('#checkboxId').val();`

Answer (score 1):

You will want to hook up an [onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) listener to the checkbox and have that call your function.

Here is some code snippet that will get you started.

```js
var resultEle = document.getElementById("result");
function showAnswer(ele) {
    if(ele.checked) {
      result.innerHTML = "You checked Yes!";
    }
    else {
      result.innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="align">
            Yes<br />
            <input type="checkbox" onchange="showAnswer(this)" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="result"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT:  Looks like you are using JQuery, my answer is plain Javascript.  I would strongly suggest you learn some vanilla javascript before using JQuery so that you can fully understand what is happening behind the scenes.  MDN has a great starters guide!  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: I love warcraft 4 O:

Answer (score 1):

**no need JS,**

you can achieve this with **CSS only solution**,

use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `+` and [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)

```css
.text {
  display: none
}
input:checked + .text {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="select">yes</span>
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <span class="text">If you have selected yes,.....</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

js:

```
if($('input').attr('checked')) {
    $('#box').append("<div>If you have selected yes,.....</div>");
}
```

html:

```
<tr>
    <td class="align" id="box">
        <div>Yes</div> 
        <input type="checkbox"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: How would I whatever I want after the Yes

Comment: I have updated my answer @RobertoFlores. I hope this helps you. If you have any doubts you can ask me :)

Answer (score 1):

To expand Andrew Herder and dippas answers for future visitors, you can do multiples on the same page using id tags also:

```
    <input id="item1-checkbox" type="checkbox" />Mark Yes
<span id="item1">You have said Yes</span>
    <input id="item2-checkbox" type="checkbox" />Mark Agree
<span id="item2">You have said Agree</span>
```

.

```
<style>
#item1 {
  display: none
}
input#item1-checkbox:checked ~ #item1 {
  display: inline-block
}
#item2 {
  display: none
}
input#item2-checkbox ~ #item2 {
  display: inline-block
}
</style>
```